# is jquery subgrid plugin work for json?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

how are you? 
I am working with jqGrid subgrid and its not working. Note that in jqGrid 3.5 demo, there is a quote...

Note: Currently subgrid can work only with xml data. Json is in progress.

So please tell me, does it really work for the subgrid?

Comment: What is the question here? It says in the demo that it will only work for xml data, not json.

Answer (score 0):

datatype json works in jqGrid v4.0